# Connect application to database when they are in separate docker containers

Tags: docker, devops

Well, the set up is simple, there should be two containers: one of them for the mysql database and the other one for web application.

What I do to run the containers,
the first one for database and the second for the app:

`docker run --name mysql-container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -p 3306:3306 -d mysql`

`docker run -p 8081:8081 myrepo/myapp`

The application tries to connect to database using localhost:3306, but as I found out the issue is that each container has its own localhost.

One of the solution I found was to add the same network for containers using `--net` and the docker commands happend to be like the following:

`docker network create my-network`

`docker run --name mysql-container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -p 3306:3306 -d 
--net my-network mysql`

`docker run --net my-network -p 8081:8081 myrepo/myapp`

Though, the web application still is not able to connect to the database. **What am I doing wrong and what is the proper flow to connect application to database when they are both inside containers?**

Comment: You need to tell the app container to connect to the IP of the DB container in `my-network`. `localhost` will not work.

Comment: @rdas Grabbed IP with `docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"` and replaced localhost with IP I grabbed inside the application, though the application still can't connect to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after additional research, I successfully managed to connect to the database.

**The approach I used is the following:**
On my host I grabbed the IP address of the docker itself but not the specific container:
`sudo ip addr show | grep docker0`

The IP address of the `docker0` I added to the database connection URL inside my application and thus application managed to connect to the database *(note: with this flow I don't add the `--net` keyword when start container)*

What definitely strange is that even adding shared network like `--net=my-nework` for both the container didn't work. Moreover I did try to use `--net=host` to share the host network with container's one, still it was unsuccessful. If there's any who can explain why it couldn't work, please - share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the name of the container (i.e. `mysql-container`) to connect to mysql. Example:

Run the mysql container:

```
docker run --name mysql-container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -p 3306:3306 -d --net my-network mysql
```

Connect from another container using the `mysql` client:

```
docker run --net my-network -it mysql mysql -u root -p db -h mysql-container
```

In your application you should replace in the database URL, whatever IP you have with `mysql-container`.

Comment: Well, I grabbed the IP of the `mysql-container` with `docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"` and added that IP into the application instead of localhost. Though, the application still cannot connect to the database

Comment: Why don"t you use the name directly. It can be resolved by the app container making everything more flexible.

Comment: If you are suggesting to replace the IP with the name of the container straight in database URL `jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/db` then as soon as the application starts, the following exception is thrown: `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-container`

Comment: Can you run successfully the second command in my answer @THE Waterfall?

Comment: Yes, definitely I can

Comment: Just to clarify: I can connect using your second command from **the host server** to mysql container